# Physics Bug in Corona Sdk

Tags: lua, sdk, box2d, coronasdk, game-physics

I have a problem in Corona SDK. The physics are screwed up. Objects move in random directions

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- main.lua
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Your code here
local physics_engine = require("physics")
physics_engine.start()


local background=display.newGroup()
local main_area=display.newGroup()
local sheetOptions =
{--animated sheet options
    width = 389,
    height = 391,
    numFrames = 10
}
--load animated image sheet
local cute_charac_sheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "spritesheet.png", sheetOptions )
local sequences_cute_charac = {
    -- consecutive frames sequence
    {--animation options for blinking
        name = "normalRun",
        start = 1,
        count = 10,
        time=800,
        loopCount = 0,
        loopDirection = "bounce"
    }
}
local function woodmaker(event)

 local wood =display.newImageRect(main_area,'wood.png',15,45)
 wood.x=event.x
 wood.y=event.y
 physics_engine.addBody(wood,'kinematic')


end
local cute_charac = display.newSprite( cute_charac_sheet,sequences_cute_charac)


main_area:insert(cute_charac)
cute_charac.x=display.contentCenterX
cute_charac.y=192.55

cute_charac:scale(0.1,0.1)

cute_charac:play()

local back_png= display.newImageRect(background,"Day_Back.png",480,270)
back_png.x=display.contentCenterX
back_png.y=display.contentCenterY
back_png:addEventListener( "tap", woodmaker )

local ground_grass=display.newImageRect(main_area,"grass.png",480,60)
ground_grass.x=display.contentCenterX
ground_grass.y=240

local grass_texture=display.newImageRect(main_area,'grassup.png',480,5)
grass_texture.x=display.contentCenterX
grass_texture.y=210

physics_engine.addBody(cute_charac,"dynamic")
physics_engine.addBody(grass_texture,'static',{bounce=0,})
```

Also removing the ground_grass fixes it.[Why is this happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPwL8.png)

Also making the wood dynamic pushes it towards the sides and if the wood is placed in the middle it moves down.

Comment: 1. You need to format your code properly so it's legible. 2. What have you done to debug it?

Comment: I'm new to corona and stack overflow so how do I format the code. also if I remove the ground_grass everything becomes normal

Comment: Highlight the code and press `ctrl-k`. And that would have been good information to include in the question. Please edit in any debugging information you have, like noticing it works when you remove the grass.

Comment: Everything moves down because gravity force. In general display objects [should not be scaled.](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/limitations/index.html) Also, use [physics.setDrawMode()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setDrawMode.html) for debbuging purposes.

Comment: Thanks, @Idurniat , removing scaling solved the problem.